# How to forward port 80 and 443 on pfSense to a (internal) nginx webserver?

Tags: firewall, pfsense, port-forwarding, gateway

Yesterday we did a "big bang" firewall switch in our company. Our new firewall is a pfSense server.
Lets say our external ip is `84.1.1.1`, pfSense is `192.168.1.1` and our web server ip is `192.168.1.2`.

---

After we made the "big switch", the pfSense interface was responding on https://84.1.1.1, this is not intended as we want to use https://84.1.1.1 (port 443) for our web server. For this reason i changed the pfSense port from 443 to 444 which "solved" this issue as port 443 is "free" for other services now.

We won't allow access to the pfSense interface from our external ip at all but that is another problem which is off topic.

---

Now i wan to forward port `443`, `80` (and in future some more) to servers in our network. For this i first want to explain how i configured the WAN connection as i noticed something.

I tried to ping (with the pfSense ping diagnostic tool) from `WAN1` (our WAN) to the web server. This did not work which means that my port forwarding also cant work at all. I think that pfSense tries to resolve this ping request via its gateway so i tried to set the gateway of `WAN1` to `none` and from this moment on i can ping the webserver from `WAN1` (via the pfSense ping diagnose tool).

**Question:** Do i need to set a Gateway to our `WAN1`? I suppose yes? And if yes, do i need to make some exclusions for internal network somewhere? Just as extra info, maybe its required, we have a static IP which directly hangs on pfSense...

**pfSense configuration**

```
WAN INTERFACE
    <wan>
        <if>igb0</if>
        <descr><![CDATA[WAN1]]></descr>
        <alias-address></alias-address>
        <alias-subnet>32</alias-subnet>
        <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        <enable></enable>
        <ipaddr>84.1.1.1</ipaddr>
        <subnet>30</subnet>
        <gateway>WAN1GW</gateway>
    </wan>

GATEWAY
    <gateways>
        <defaultgw4>WAN1GW</defaultgw4>
        <defaultgw6></defaultgw6>
        <gateway_item>
            <interface>wan</interface>
            <gateway>84.1.1.2</gateway>
            <name>WAN1GW</name>
            <weight>1</weight>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <descr><![CDATA[WAN1 gateway]]></descr>
        </gateway_item>
    </gateways>

OUTBOUND NAT RULES
    <nat>
        <outbound>
            <mode>advanced</mode>
            <rule>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.10.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <sourceport></sourceport>
                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - AXN_INTRA to WAN1]]></descr>
                <target></target>
                <targetip></targetip>
                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <poolopts></poolopts>
                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                <disabled></disabled>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <dstport>500</dstport>
                <created>
                    <time>1589543460</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                </created>
                <updated>
                    <time>1591883208</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.29 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </updated>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.11.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <dstport>500</dstport>
                <target></target>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <staticnatport></staticnatport>
                <descr><![CDATA[Auto created rule for ISAKMP - AXN_SRV to WAN1]]></descr>
                <created>
                    <time>1589888715</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                </created>
                <disabled></disabled>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.20.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <sourceport></sourceport>
                <descr></descr>
                <target></target>
                <targetip></targetip>
                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <poolopts></poolopts>
                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <updated>
                    <time>1590582795</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </updated>
                <created>
                    <time>1590582795</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </created>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.10.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <sourceport></sourceport>
                <descr></descr>
                <target></target>
                <targetip></targetip>
                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <poolopts></poolopts>
                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <updated>
                    <time>1591883222</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.29 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </updated>
                <created>
                    <time>1591883222</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.29 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </created>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.12.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <sourceport></sourceport>
                <descr><![CDATA[Default NAT rule for axn_cloud]]></descr>
                <target></target>
                <targetip></targetip>
                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <poolopts></poolopts>
                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <created>
                    <time>1589896652</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </created>
                <updated>
                    <time>1590140198</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </updated>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <source>
                    <network>10.128.11.0/24</network>
                </source>
                <sourceport></sourceport>
                <descr><![CDATA[Default NAT rule for axn_srv]]></descr>
                <target></target>
                <targetip></targetip>
                <targetip_subnet></targetip_subnet>
                <interface>wan</interface>
                <poolopts></poolopts>
                <source_hash_key></source_hash_key>
                <destination>
                    <any></any>
                </destination>
                <created>
                    <time>1589888715</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[Manual Outbound NAT Switch]]></username>
                </created>
                <updated>
                    <time>1590140250</time>
                    <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
                </updated>
            </rule>
        </outbound>
    </nat>
```

---

About the forwarding itself, i configured it like this:

[image]
as i set `Filter rule association` to `Add associated filter rule` during the creation of the `Port forward`, pfSense automatically created the corresponding/required firewall rule on the `WAN1` port.

[image]

**Question:** Do i need some additional configurations to forward port `443` and `80` near the configuration i already did? (the port forward and creating the required firewall rules)

Comment: "_I tried to ping (with the pfSense ping diagnostic tool) from WAN1 (our WAN) to the web server. This did not work which means that my port forwarding also cant work at all._" Ping and web services really have nothing to do with each other. Ping uses ICMP, but web services use HTML on TCP. Those are completely different protocols. in fact, ICMP (ping) does not use or know about other transport protocols, such as TCP or UDP, nor does it know about the addresses (ports) those other protocols use.

Comment: Thanks, i understand what you mean. How can this help solve my problem? Port 2xxx for our OpenVPN server can be forwarded without any issue. Clients can connect to the server which is "behind" pfSense

Comment: Forwarding 80/443 was trivial and the bottom two screenshots match what I have.  I find it interesting that you've blocked out a lot of the items in the title bar, one of which is not on a standard pfsense install.  Are there other add-ons too?  It seems there's a chance you have something else that's conflicting.  Have you looked through logs for clues?  I didn't create any rules in the firewall myself.  I only added NAT port forward rules and let it create the firewall rules automatically.  Did you do it another way?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I run the same thing nginx on a different server that handout certificates to your services.  First you need icmp echo reply configured because, for the dns provider to see you need that service and I use cloudns and they are good.
Second on pfsense you need NAT configured to work and then 1:1 as well configured to allow the ports 80 and 443 to be open on your pfsense router. I will stop here for more info and I can give you pictures from my setup if it's easy this way. There are more steps to go through the configuration.